# Child class name in parent class function at run time Python

Tags: python

## Is it possible to find out which child class has called the parent class function in the parent class function

```
class ParentClass:

    def print_child_class_name(self):
        print('how to find print the child class name here')

class ChildClass1(ParentClass):
    pass

class ChildClass2(ParentClass):
   pass

child_1 = ChildClass1()
child_2 = ChildClass2()
child_1.print_child_class_name()
child_2.print_child_class_name()
```

Comment: Kindly mark the best answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'd use: `self.__class__.__name__` to retrieve the name of the class of the instance `self`.

```
class ParentClass:

    def print_child_class_name(self):
        print(self.__class__.__name__)

class ChildClass1(ParentClass):
    pass

class ChildClass2(ParentClass):
   pass

child_1 = ChildClass1()
child_2 = ChildClass2()
child_1.print_child_class_name() #Prints ChildClass1
child_2.print_child_class_name() # Prints ChildClass2
```

Comment: Thanks. This Worked

Comment: What if the static function of the class has been called ?

Answer (score 0):

## Use `self.__class__.__name__`

```
class ParentClass:

    def print_child_class_name(self):
        print('Class Name: {}'.format(self.__class__.__name__))
```